# Not understanding the format of date in json

Tags: json, python-2.7

I have a json data in which there is a field called "createdDate" which is mentioned in the below code.I am parsing the json using python. I am not understanding the format. I want that date in the format yyyy-mm-dd. Please help.

```
{
  "id": 13553,
  "parentId": 0,
  "userId": 88022,
  "createdDate": 1381658700000,
  "status": "1"
}
```

Comment: If you want it in that format, create a string with what you want. It's currently using the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01.

Comment: I think i can convert '1381658700000' into yyyy-mm-dd format using python datetime. But i have tried, i could not solve it. Can you help ?

Comment: Please show what you tried, and someone who knows Python should be able to help you.

Comment: datetime.fromtimestamp(1381658700000)

Comment: That just returns a datetime, not a string. Try `datetime.fromtimestamp(...).isoformat()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That is a timestamp in milliseconds.  `datetime.utctimestamp` will convert a value in seconds to a `datetime` instance.  From there you can format it as a string.

```
# assuming the parsed json is stored in my_data
timestamp = int(my_data['createdDate'])
# split out the seconds and remaining milliseconds
seconds, milli = divmod(timestamp, 1000)
# convert to datetime instance and add microseconds (milliseconds * 1000)
dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(seconds).replace(microsecond=milli * 1000)
# print string representation
print dt.strftime('yyyy-mm-dd')
```